# Comparação de elementos de um vetor

Tags: r

Pessoal preciso de uma função que verifique se todas as coordenadas do vetor são iguais.

```
a = rep(1, 5)
```

Que a saída anterior seja TRUE.

```
b = c(rep(1, 4),2)
```

Que a saída anterior seja FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi,

```
all(a[1] == a)
```

e

```
all(b[1] == b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Wagner. Ela está correta, mas não funciona se os vetores contiverem valores `NA`.

```
> a = rep(NA, 5)
> all(a[1] == a)
[1] NA
> b = c(rep(1, 4),NA)
> all(b[1] == b)
[1] NA
```

Neste caso você poderia usar as seguintes comparações:

```
> isTRUE(all.equal(rep(a[1], length(a)), a))
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(all.equal(rep(b[1], length(b)), b))
[1] FALSE
```